# context.PostAsync is excruciatingly slow - what did I do wrong?

Tags: c#, performance, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

**Setup**

I am using Bot Framework and C#. My bot is deployed to facebook. The code is deployed to an Azure app service.

**Problem**

It takes around 9 seconds for the bot to respond to any message.

**What I tried**

I used the `Stopwatch` class in C# to measure what function takes so much time. Turns out it's the `await context.PostAsync()`, the function that posts the message.

Each call takes around 1.5 seconds, so if I send 4 messages to the user, the bot takes more than 6 seconds for that, plus another 1 second for various API calls, and 2 seconds in the Message Controller.

Why could the `context.PostAsync()` call take so much time?

**Possible weird solution:**

I had ~30 sessions logged in on the facebook account that receives the messages. After going to facebook.com and clicking 'Log out all sessions' under Settings, it seems to got much 2-3 times faster. But I am not sure that this was the solution.

Comment: You need to add more details about your implementation to get some feedback

Comment: @NicolasR I am not sure what other details could be useful. I think I've added everything: I use Azure + C# + Bot Framework + Facebook. The minimum reproducible case is send `await context.PostAsync("test");` four times in a row.

Comment: The time after logging out of all sessions seems to be in the ballpark of "normal".   Have you tested on the [emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator) and noticed similar or varying behavior?

Comment: @JasonSowers the emulator is blazing fast